# array as hidden variable

Tags: java, jsp, struts

can array be used as hidden variable on jsp.....like I have a form i.e a simple java 
class,I want it to be as hidden variable can I do it..

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HTTP request parameters can only be strings. So you either have to convert it to a single string (maybe a commaseparated string?), but you need to convert it back yourself, or you have to use multiple hidden input values (all with the same name), which is generally a much better solution. In plain JSP/Servlet you can get them back using `HttpServletRequest#getParameterValues()` and Struts is smart enough to see that.

```
<logic:iterate id="foo" name="bean" property="arrayOrList">  
    <html:hidden name="paramName" property="propertyName" indexed="true" />  
</logic:iterate>
```

Answer (score 0):

just write multiple hidden elements with the same name en different values. struts will see that it is supposed to be an array

Answer (score 0):

agree with BalusC in addition to that 
you can try following

adding [] at the end of the name , keeping name and property same and adding multiple values.
for example

```
<html:hidden name="name1[]" property="status" value="value1" />
<html:hidden name="name1[]" property="status" value="value2" />
<html:hidden name="name1[]" property="status" value="value3" />
```